# Google Colab cells opening halfway

Tags: google-colaboratory

[[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3UIV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6lSV.png)

every time i open an uploaded notebook, the code cells for the notebook opens halfway, thus hiding more than 80% of the rest of the code. Please how do i fix this? This issue does not surface when i create a new notebook, its always when opening an uploaded notebook.

I have tried to unhide code cells, yet it did not work, also wanted to expand all sections, but the icon wasn't clickable.